# header is working on localhost but not working on online hosting

Tags: php, session

```
$save = "UPDATE user SET M_ID='{$_SESSION['ha1'] }' WHERE U_ID ='{$_SESSION['ID'] }'";
    $reslt = mysqli_query($conn, $save) or die(mysql_error());
    header('location: treatment.php');
```

the header not working online but it works on localhost, any help please?

Comment: In what way is it not working? Is it failing to connect to the database?

Comment: no it connects on db and the update query is working but not transfaring me to the requested page (treatment.php) it reload the same page iam in again

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
mysql_error()
```

to:

```
mysqli_error($conn)
```

And enable PHP error reporting to see what happens when your script executes.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change "location" in lowercase for "Location" ("L" in uppercase)

he problem may come from using Windows in local and Linux on the server